# relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol _ZTISt13runtime_error@@GLIBCXX_3.4 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

The project I am attempting compile is not in any way complex, and references nothing but the standard library and one self-contained library (everything compiles fine on another system). As indicated by the title, it can't even link against something in the standard library, due to things in there not having been compiled with `-fPIC`, supposedly. I didn't build it myself, nor do I want to, and reinstalling things with `apt` didn't seem to resolve the "recompile with -fPIC" issue.

I will say that I think one possible source of the issue is due to `gcc-multilib` or something being installed earlier, but I think that was purged. I don't know, maybe something was overwritten or a conflict arose. Might not even be related. Any ideas?

Running Ubuntu 18.04

```
g++ -I inc -I /usr/include/mono-2.0 -MMD -MF dep/Nonsense.d -std=c++17 -O3 -fno-stack-protector -fno-unroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wno-ignored-optimization-argument -c -o obj/Nonsense.o src/Nonsense.cpp
g++ -I inc -I /usr/include/mono-2.0 -MMD -MF dep/Socket.d -std=c++17 -O3 -fno-stack-protector -fno-unroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wno-ignored-optimization-argument -c -o obj/Socket.o src/Socket.cpp
g++ -shared -flto -o libNonsense.so obj/Nonsense.o obj/Socket.o -Llib -lenet
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: obj/Socket.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTISt13runtime_error@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:22: recipe for target 'libNonsense.so' failed
make: *** [libNonsense.so] Error 1
```

Comment: is this windows?

Comment: Missing too much information. We need to know the platform, how you configured, typical command line, linker command, etc. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` would probably resolve the issue if we knew the specifics.

Comment: I've added some more context, except configuration, as this project is so simple, simple commands to `g++` would suffice to build it. I have a feeling that something is installed incorrectly, as compiling something this simple shouldn't cause any issues like this.

Comment: Please show us the command you used to build `obj/Socket.o`.

Comment: You need to do what the error message says. Add the `-fPIC` flag  when compiling your source code files and also add `-fPIC` when you are creating (linking) your libNonsense.so library.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: @MonatheMonad Then you might not have done it correctly. You should copy paste the same 3 lines of output showing the commands being run, and the error message again so we can see what's going on. (Keep in mind to recompile everything when you have changed the compiler and linker flags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to *recompile* with `-fPIC`.  Your current compiler command does not show the `-fPIC` option:

> `g++ -I inc -I /usr/include/mono-2.0 -MMD -MF dep/Socket.d -std=c++17 -O3 -fno-stack-protector -fno-unroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wno-ignored-optimization-argument -c -o obj/Socket.o src/Socket.cpp`

Same for `-flto` by the way—this flag also has to be specified when compiling in order to be effective.

Comment: This pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Strange, I did this before and it somehow didn't work, but now it does. Maybe the cleaning process somehow didn't delete the old object files. I was adding the fPIC flag everywhere and it wasn't working, but it seems to have been resolved now.

Comment: @Florian Weimer I'm using g++ as well and I'm getting the same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404608/compilation-fails-due-to-relocation-error please check

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is compulsory to compile with the -fPIC flag in 64bits platform. If you are making a 32-bits project with linkink with 32-bits library; you don't need -fPIC.
Indeed, without -fPIC, the dynamic linker recalculates adresses for global variables and functions (which are not known in advance in the step of compilation). However, in a 64-bits system, it is not possible to use this technique as it is required to guess in advance the size of adress.
PIC (Position Independent Code), a more sophisticated and complicated process is used. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64 for explanations.