# Compilation fails due to relocation error

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, compilation

I'm trying to compile [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ann_1.1.2.tar.gz).  I compiled using the following command,

```
make linux-g ++
```

Later when I try to use this in another code, the code is not compiling. I'm getting the following error,

```
>  relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZSt4cerr@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can
> not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

After going through various questions , I tried adding the following line to CMAKE,

```
set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

but still, it doesn't work. how can I fix  this?

Comment: did you tired `make clean` (to build from scratch)?

Comment: @MarekR yes, I did `make clean` and recompiled but for some reason, it is still not working as expected

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: I'm using 64 bit system

Comment: Could you please post that as an answer? It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a proper solution, but as a workaround, you can replace the line

```
"C++ = g++"
```

with

```
"C++ = g++ -fPIC"
```

in the file `Make-config` and then recompile.